# Does the compiler optimize a variable declaration?

Tags: go, compiler-optimization

Given an iteration:

```
 LOOP:
 for {       
       select {
       case <-timeout:
         t.Fatal("Timed out")
       default:
         if Count() == int64(num) {
            break LOOP
         }
         time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
       }
    }
```

`Count()` returns an `int64`, so I need a conversion, and `Count` changes, so we are checking here until `Count()` returns an expected value - possibly thousands of iterations.

Does the compiler optimize this conversion? 
Or is it better to convert `num`, which is used before in other places as `int` and not `int64`, beforehand before starting the loop?

Comment: There are several compilers and each changes constantly.

Comment: Write code that does  what it needs to do and makes sense when you read it. Benchmark it to see if performance is acceptable. If it isn't, profile it to see where the slowdown is. Optimize that. These kinds of micro-optimizations with no cause to think they have any meaningful impact on real-world performance are completely pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it's optimized might depend on other code you didn't show, and also on compiler version / target architecture. Although I doubt when concurrency  and other function calls are involved, the performance bottleneck will be an `int` => `int64` conversion. Most likely you won't see any difference if you get rid of that conversion.

Also note that if the architecture you use is 64-bit, the size (and memory representation and interpretation) of `int` and `int64` is the same, which means the conversion does not incur any cost, it just changes the type (how it's interpreted).

**Edit:** Since you're using sleep anyway, getting rid of the conversion would be pointless. Use whichever makes your code more readable.

Comment: oh awesome! thanks. Was using go `1.13.5`
I added an edit to show the complete code. Basically we are iterating until the condition is met, at which point we just break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The Go amd64 assembler:

```
0000000000457bb0 <main.Equality>:
  457bb0:   48 8b 44 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
  457bb5:   48 8b 4c 24 10          mov    0x10(%rsp),%rcx
  457bba:   48 39 c8                cmp    %rcx,%rax
  457bbd:   0f 94 44 24 18          sete   0x18(%rsp)
  457bc2:   c3                      retq
```

As expected, it's fast.

The compiler knows that, for amd64, `int` is the same as `int64`. No conversion is necessary.

Reference:

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)

---

`opt.go`:

```
package main

//go:noinline
func Equality(a int64, b int) bool {
    return a == int64(b)
}

func main() {
    var a, b = int64(42), int(39)
    println(Equality(a, b))
}
```

Dump:

```
$ go build opt.go
$ objdump -d opt > opt.dump
```

Comment: this answer keeps an air of mystery.